# how to append cosntant in all columns of header in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For example here is my Existing header

```
DataPartition|^|TimeStamp|^|Source.organizationId|^|Source.sourceId|^|FilingDateTime|^|SourceTypeCode|^|DocumentId|^|Dcn|^|DocFormat|^|StatementDate|^|IsFilingDateTimeEstimated|^|ContainsPreliminaryData|^|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate|^|CumulativeAdjustmentFactor|^|ContainsRestatement|^|FilingDateTimeUTCOffset|^|ThirdPartySourceCode|^|ThirdPartySourcePriority|^|SourceTypeId|^|ThirdPartySourceCodeId|^|FFAction|!|
```

I want to create header like below

```
DataPartition_1|^|TimeStamp|^|Source.organizationId|^|Source.sourceId|^|FilingDateTime_1|^|SourceTypeCode_1|^|DocumentId_1|^|Dcn_1|^|DocFormat_1|^|StatementDate_1|^|IsFilingDateTimeEstimated_1|^|ContainsPreliminaryData_1|^|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate_1|^|CumulativeAdjustmentFactor_1|^|ContainsRestatement_1|^|FilingDateTimeUTCOffset_1|^|ThirdPartySourceCode_1|^|ThirdPartySourcePriority_1|^|SourceTypeId_1|^|ThirdPartySourceCodeId_1|^|FFAction_1
```

Except for columns `TimeStamp|^|Source.organizationId|^|Source.sourceId` I want to append _1 in all header columns

I have done it by using with `withColumn` but using this I have to do for all columns .

Is there any easy way to do it like using `foldLeft`  ?

Comment: how are you generating this header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define a list of the columns you want to skip:

```
val columnsToAvoid = List("TimeStamp","Source.organizationId","Source.sourceId")
```

Then you can `foldLeft` over the column list of the dataFrame (given by `df.columns`) renaming each column that it's not contained in the columnsToAvoid list and returning the unchanged dataFrame otherwise.

```
df.columns.foldLeft(df)((acc, elem) => 
                     if (columnsToAvoid.contains(elem)) acc 
                     else acc.withColumnRenamed(elem, elem+"_1"))
```

A quick example here:

Original DF

```
+-----+------+-----------+
| word| value|  TimeStamp|
+-----+------+-----------+
|wordA|valueA|45435345435|
|wordB|valueB|  454244345|
|wordC|valueC|32425425435|
+-----+------+-----------+
```

Operation:

```
df.columns.foldLeft(df)((acc, elem) => if (columnsToAvoid.contains(elem)) acc else acc.withColumnRenamed(elem, elem+"_1")).show
```

Result:

```
+------+-------+-----------+
|word_1|value_1|  TimeStamp|
+------+-------+-----------+
| wordA| valueA|45435345435|
| wordB| valueB|  454244345|
| wordC| valueC|32425425435|
+------+-------+-----------+
```